# Why rubocop offenses (C: Carriage return character detected) in Windows 10 pro but not in Mac?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubocop

The code below:

```rb
def fix(value)
  value << 'xyz'
  value = value.upcase
  value.concat('!')
end

s = 'hello'
t = fix(s)

puts s
puts t
```

doesn't show any rubocop offense in mac, but shows

```
C: Carriage return character detected
def fix(value) ...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in windows 10 pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix and Windows are using different characters to indicate a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). While Unix uses a `line feed` (`"\n"`), Windows uses `carriage return + line feed` (`"\r\n"`).

Just configure the IDE on the Windows machine to just use the Unix version.